# Android: distinguish between device resolutions when providing resources

Tags: android, xml, screen-resolution

I have and android project providing different dimens.xml for different screen resoultions. I am doing so by defining values-swXXXdp folders in my /res folder.

However, I am now having trouble distinguishing the following two screen resolutions:

1. 768x1280, 160dpi from
2. 768x1024, 160dpi

What I tried so far:

- values-sw768dp is used for both
- values-sw768dp-notlong is used for both even if values-sw768dp is present
- values-h768dp-w1024dp is ignored
- values-w768dp-h1024dp is ignored

Does anyone have a hint, what folder name I have to use, to provide a dimens.xml ONLY for screen resolution number 2?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone have a hint, what folder name I have to use, to provide a dimens.xml ONLY for screen resolution number 2?

I don't think it is possible, at least not with *w* or *h* qualifiers. Why? According to [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) guide on Android Developers you can specify minimum screen width or height required to load certain resource, but not maximum.

Lets have a look what happens if you have resources organized like this:

```
res/
    values/
    values-h1024dp/
```

Android has [defined behavior](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch) of matching resources depending on device configuration. When you open application on device with screen height of 800dp, best match would be `values`, because 1024dp doesn't fit in 800dp. However if you'll open same app on larger device with screen height with 1024 *or higher*, it will use `values-h1024dp` directory.

Unfortunately you want to use second resources directory only for device of certain dimensions, i.e. 768dpx1024dp.

Providing resources in Android is designed in different way you'd expect, but has a [way to achieve what you need](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources) - alias resources.

To provide resource directories structure where only one directory matches device with configuration w1024dp, I'd create following structure:

```
res/
    values/
    values-h1024dp/
    values-h1025dp/
```

And in `values-h1025dp` create xml files containing aliases for resources in `values`. This way you can have one resource file that matches all devices except those with screen height of 1024dp.

Please note, it will work for devices with configuration you've specified, but only in landscape mode, since I used only *h* qualifier.